# can't display log output of dll shared lib in MATLAB

Tags: .net, matlab, logging, dll

I have this shared lib as dll file and I'm trying to load and use it in MATLAB, it contains functions that output some Log and I want to display this output the MATLAB Command Window.

```
%MATLAB Code for loading and using the functions
NET.addAssembly('C:\Users\User1\Desktop\SomeLib.dll');
import Lib.DesiredClass.*;
myFun();%I'm expecting here an output.
```

I already did my research and found a way to display that output in CMD (separate window) with the following command.

```
C:\Users\User1>matlab -wait -log
```

and then running the same code in MATLAB, I get the desired output in CMD but I want to display it in MATLAB command Window.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. Are you saying that `myfun()` only writes to system command line, and not MATLAB command line?

Comment: Yes, I want to direct that output to MATLAB Command Window

Comment: But, if you run it inside MATLAB, it doesnt print?! Or does the function create a log file that you can then read in MATLAB? I am a bit confused about this

Comment: no, it only outputs if the the function isn't void and returns some value, I can only use the cmd to view the Log outputted with the command previously mentioned.

Comment: Well, I still don't get how it works, but in matlab, you can call `system(some_OS_command)` or just  `!some_OS_command` to call the OS cmd in the MATLAB cmd and print in the MATLAB cmd. Hope that helps

Comment: I tried that but the issuse is that my function is void and thus it doesn't return any values.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "my function is void", that is not MALTAB terminology

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the MATLAB Command window by writing to stdout or stderr. You need to call the [`mexPrintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexprintf.html) function in the MATLAB API to do so.

This means that the function in your DLL cannot write to the MATLAB Command window unless you write it explicitly to link to a MATLAB library and call `mexPrintf`.

The simplest solution is to have the DLL output to a log file.